# Scrapy: extract text in li without a class inside when there is some time a strong after text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I have a problem trying to get text in a `<li>` because sometimes there is a `<strong>` inside and sometimes there is not.

```
<div class="short-description" itemprop="description">
  <div class="std">
    <ul>
      <li><span class="orange-caret"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>Diseñada para trabajar con agua limpia como pueden ser bombeos de pozos y manantiales o en sistemas de riego</li>
      <li><span class="orange-caret"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>Uso industrial y agrícola</li>
      <li><span class="orange-caret"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>Altura máxima: <strong>30 m</strong></li>
      <li><span class="orange-caret"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>Flujo máximo <strong>120 L/min</strong></li>
      <li><span class="orange-caret"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>Profundidad de inmersión máxima: <strong>80 m</strong></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the failing code and how is it failing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 response.xpath('//*[@class="std"]/ul/li//text()') #use .get() or .getall()
```

Comment: this error is in output >>> response.xpath('//*[@class="std"]/ul/li//text()).getall()
  File "<console>", line 1
    response.xpath('//*[@class="std"]/ul/li//text()).getall()
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>>

Comment: Missing  right hand side quotation mark. I 've updated

Comment: >>> response.xpath('//*[@id="product_addtocart_form"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/ul/li//text()').getall()
['Diseñada para trabajar con agua limpia como pueden ser bombeos de pozos y manantiales o en sistemas de riego', 'Uso industrial y agrícola', 'Altura máxima: ', '30 m', 'Flujo máximo ', '120 L/min', 'Profundidad de inmersión máxima: ', '80 m']
>>>

Comment: if anyone needs to get whole text inside a li even there is another tags inside must add **//text()** adter the last tag og the response, thanks to @Fazlul